Sort numbers in Latex file between delimiters
I have a latex file which consists of a list of about 10,000 records consisting of a head word plus reference numbers separated by a comma. Some numbers are marked with latex codes.
ʾallik \refnumbers{9, 4306, 12, 9917, \textbf{28}, 8, 17, 13, 462, 3}
ʾalmin \refnumbers{9, 4306, 12, \textbf{26}, 008, \page{17}, 13, 462, 3}
ʾaran \refnumbers{282, \textbf{300-2}, 391, 829, 1021, 18, 361}

I want to sort these numbers between the { } in the appropriate alphanumeric sequences. The desired result looks like this:
ʾallik \refnumbers{3, 8, 9, 12, 13, \textbf{28}, 462, 4306, 9917}
ʾalmin \refnumbers{3, 008, 9, 12, 13, \textbf{26}, 462, 4306, \page{17}}
ʾaran \refnumbers{18, 282, \textbf{300-2}, 361, 391, 829, 1021}

Sorting can be done with all types of applications, which I tried (sed, perl, awk) but somehow I cannot grasp how to skip the begin of the record and start the sorting at { and end it at }. My preference is a perl command line or a perl script.

You want \textbf{28} to be considered 28, I take it, but what do you want \textbf{300-2} to be considered as? 298, or 300, or something else? Also, why is \page{17} last? You seem to be sometimes considering them to be their numbers, and sometimes not.

There are some inconsistent entries in your data, the "latex codes", e.g. \textbf{28} which you sometimes rank as their numerical value in the example, and sometimes not. This solution uses their numeric value.
Since we have irregular strings, it is convenient with a Schwartzian transform, to store the original string, while using the numerical value in the sort.
The Schwartzian transform is read from the end to the beginning of the expression, and the benefit is that one does not need to capture the numerical part of a string multiple times while sorting.
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {   # use while (<>) for your own data
    my ($hdr, $num) = split ' ', $_, 2;                       # max 2 fields
    my ($begin, $mid, $end) = $num =~ /^(\\\pL+{)(.*)(})$/;   # capture string parts
    my $new = join ", ",                   # END join string again
        map $_->[0],                       # transform back to original string
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }       # sort based on numeric part
        map { [ $_, ($_) =~ /(\d+)/ ] }    # transform into array with org + numeric part
        split (/ *, */, $mid);             # START split original by comma and spaces

        print "$hdr $begin$new$end\n";     # print finished string
}

__DATA__
ʾallik \refnumbers{9, 4306, 12, 9917, \textbf{28}, 8, 17, 13, 462, 3}
ʾalmin \refnumbers{9, 4306, 12, \textbf{26}, 008, \page{17}, 13, 462, 3}
ʾaran \refnumbers{282, \textbf{300-2}, 391, 829, 1021, 18, 361}

Output:
ʾallik \refnumbers{3, 8, 9, 12, 13, 17, \textbf{28}, 462, 4306, 9917}
ʾalmin \refnumbers{3, 008, 9, 12, 13, \page{17}, \textbf{26}, 462, 4306}
ʾaran \refnumbers{18, 282, \textbf{300-2}, 361, 391, 829, 1021}

This output is based on the first numerical value in the string, based on \d+. Hence, 300-2 is not considered an expression, and only 300 is captured. Nor does it handle scientific notation, or floating point. This is possible to add, if needed.
To use the program with your own data in external files or stdin, change the file handle <DATA> to <>.

Thanks again for your trouble. The number 28 occurs both as \textbf{28} and as 28. The list is actually an index to a historical encyclopedia of about 6500 entries all of them numbered. The label textbf means that the item is found as a headword in the entry that is numbered 28. The bare number means the item is mentioned in passim in the entry text. 300-2 means that this  item (homograph) occurs in the headwords: 300, 301 and 302. \page{17} means that the item occurs in passim in other texts outside the numbered encyclopedia items. Page then serves as a reference to the manuscript page.

I see. Well, then this solution works as expected. With the caveat that 300-2 is considered only as 300, not 301 and 302. And there is no special consideration for \page tag.

The script works! Thanks a lot. It only works when the records are added below under DATA, not als STDIN, but that is probably OK.

@RobertE Yes, DATA is a special file handle for text inside the program file. If you want to use stdin, the file handle is STDIN. Though most commonly people would use while (<>) called diamond operator, which uses STDIN or ARGV, depending on which is used.

You can do something like this:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_int {
    my $v = $_[0];
    if($v =~ /\{(\d+).*\}/) {
        return $1;
    }
    return $v;
}

sub compare_with_text {
    my $aint = get_int($a);
    my $bint = get_int($b);
    return $aint <=> $bint;
}

while(<DATA>) {
    /^(.*?) \\refnumbers\{(.*)\}$/;
    my @arr = split /,\s*/, $2;
    @arr = sort compare_with_text @arr;
    print "$1 \\refnumbers\{";
    print join ", ", @arr;
    print "}\n";
}

__DATA__
ʾallik \refnumbers{9, 4306, 12, 9917, \textbf{28}, 8, 17, 13, 462, 3}
ʾalmin \refnumbers{9, 4306, 12, \textbf{26}, 008, \page{17}, 13, 462, 3}
ʾaran \refnumbers{282, \textbf{300-2}, 391, 829, 1021, 18, 361}


Thanks for the script. When I use it it gives an error: Use of uninitialized value $2 in split at sorteer-num.pl line 21,  line 2. \refnumbers{}. It also fails when the file is piped through the script. It is probably a typo somewhere?

If the match on the previous line fails, $2 is undefined. You should probably check that it does not fail, e.g. unless (/ .... /) { die "Cannot find core text" }.  Also, the $1 will be in danger, since it will be from the most recently used pattern match -- i.e. the ones during the sort in get_int().

Don't use the regex special variables unless you know the match succeeded. Otherwise you'll get the values from the previous successful match (a small but important difference to what @TLP said, but that's what they meant).
